# Am I thinking about the Argument Principle in the correct way?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, roots

I know that, by the Argument Principle, the number of zeroes of a function f inside a simple closed contour $\gamma$ minus the number of poles inside $\gamma$ = the number of times that the image curve f($\gamma$) winds around the origin in the w-plane.

For many problems that use applications of the Argument Principle and Rouche's Theorem, the application is either on a disk or an annulus, and these problems are pretty straightforward and very easy to memorize.

But for applications to, say, a quadrant or a half-plane, the problem becomes significantly harder to solve - at least for me.

My question is:  If I want to apply the Argument principle on something like a quarter-circle to find the number of roots of f inside it, how do I keep track of the argument of the image curve f($\gamma$)?

For example, the quarter circle in the first quadrant would have three edges to it.  If f(edge 1) gives a half-circle centered at zero, then do I count this as "the image curve has winded the origin 1/2 time, counterclockwise."?

Then for example f(edge 2) gives some other half circle (different radius), then do I also count this as another $\pi$ contribution to the argument of f($\gamma$)?

And say finally f(edge 3) gives yet another half circle, then count this as another contribution of $\pi$ to the argument of f($\gamma$).

So, in *total* I say that "f($\gamma$) winded around the origin in the w-plane 1.5 times, so by the Argument Principle, f must have one root inside the quarter-circle, $\gamma$."

Would I be correctly applying the Argument Principle?

And since the image curve wounded 1.5 times around the origin, but roots and poles are only expressed in integers, we round the number down to an integer - hence I get one zero inside the quarter-circle.

Please feel free to offer any comments or suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you keep track of where $f(\gamma)$ goes as you traverse the entire closed contour, even if that contour is defined by different equations on different sections. But note that $f(\gamma)$ will always end up where you started it, because both points are simply $f$ applied to whatever starting/ending point you chose. (Here it's important that $f$ be meromorphic inside $\gamma$.) So you will never get a non-integer when you do the calculation. — In terms of actual calculation, do you also know the formulation of the Argument Principle that involves integrating $f'(z)/f(z)$?

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, I'm sketching an example on paper and just want to clarify:  so, the image curve f($\gamma$) will always close itself in the end?  And if this is true, then is not necessarily saying that the total argument of $f(\gamma)$, i.e., the number of the times it winds the origin in the w-plane, is *always* in multiples of $2\pi$, right?  And that the example I gave in my question post is a possibility -- and in that case, we "round down" and say that there must only be 1 pole in the quarter-circle.  Am I still doing ok with my thinking?  Thanks,

Comment: And yes, I am aware of the integral form, which I think defines the winding number of f($\gamma$) - but I don't think that I have ever used it, @GregMartin.

Comment: It will indeed always close; yes, it is always an integer multiple of $2\pi$ (assuming that $f(\gamma)$ never goes through $0$), so you'll never have to round down. So if your computation is yielding a non-integer number of zeros/poles, then you've done something wrong (or left something relevant out of your OP).

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, specifically, I've been trying to find the number of roots of $z^5 +3z +1$ in the first quadrant, but I am stuck on the last part of my work.  Showing that this polynomial has no roots on the half-lines -- the boundary of the first quadrant -- is easy.  Then considering a quarter circle, showing f(edge 1) along the real axis is real and therefore has zero argument is also not hard.

Comment: Then f(edge 2 = quarter-circular arc) and letting R go to infinity gives an image curve $R^5 e^{i5\theta}$, and since theta runs from 0 to pi/2, the image is a circle centered at 0, traversed **5/4** times counterclockwise.  
Finally, f(edge 3 = the part of the imaginary axis, running back down to the origin) gives an image curve of $(iy)^5 + (3iy) + 1$ = $i(y^5+3y) + 1$ with R $\ge y \ge 0$.  How do I evaluate the argument of this last image curve?

Comment: I know the formula is $tan^{-1} \frac {Imf(z)}{Ref(z)}$, but I am having trouble making any statements about the behavior of f(edge 3).  So, I only know that the image curve from f(edge1) + f(edge 2), so far, has accumulated a total argument of $\frac{5\pi}{2}$, i.e., it has traversed a circle (around the origin) 5/4 times.  What do you think?  Thanks, @GregMartin.

Comment: (I had posted this in a previous question but have not gotten any responses, so I summarized it here in the comments for you, in case you can help :-).  I don't know how to get unstuck at the last part of the problem.  Thanks @GregMartin.)

Comment: Good summary! On that last edge, you start at $1+(R^5+3R)i$, which has argument extremely close to $\pi/2$ (basically vertical). Then $f$(edge2) stays within the first quadrant and ends up at $1$, which has argument $0$. The change in argument on that edge is therefore $-\pi/2$, or $1/4$ of a clockwise circle.

Comment: ...which adds up to a total argument of 2pi (5pi/2 - pi/2), so that the image curve, in total, winds around the origin in the w-plane exactly once counterclockwise, and so there is only one root in the first quadrant :-). Thank you so much for your time and patience, @GregMartin!  Have a great night!

Comment: Actually, it's 5am here and just getting ready to leave the library and get some sleep, but I better ask you one last follow-up question, if you don't mind answering:  f(edge 1)+f(edge 2) had accumulated a total argument of 5pi/2, but then f(edge3), given by arctan(Imf(z) / Ref(z)) is extremely close to pi/2 for R sufficiently large, but then makes its way down to 1, with argument = 0.  But ... is there a *jump* from 5pi/2 to pi/2?  I'm guessing that there can't be, and that there should be some form of continuity with the image curve's movement in the w-plane.  What do you think @GregMartin?

Comment: ...it sort of *seems* like there's a jump, though...

Comment: ...or probably not, the *accumulation* of 5pi/2 probably doesn't necessarily mean that the image curve is *located* at an argument of 5pi/2... e.g., after the accumulation of 5pi/2 argument, the image curve probably ended up extremely close to the imaginary axis (but still in quadrant I) in the w-plane...

Comment: I would love to hear your thoughts on this last bit -- thanks so much @GregMartin.  Goodnight! :-)

Comment: You told *me* where $$f(edge2) ends up!—at $1+i(R^5+3R)$, which is in quadrant 1. Scanning your comments: when $f$(edge3) makes its way down to $1$, its argument there is $2\pi$, not $0$. That's more or less the whole point about the argument principle: you can't tell just what the argument of $1$ (or any $z$ on the image curve) just from the value alone—it could be $0$ or $2\pi$ or $-10\pi$ or any integer multiple of $2\pi$. You have to trace the entire image curve to find out.

Comment: Ah, absolutely.  Thanks so much for your help, @GregMartin.  Have a great day :-)